# Can I include a common code block in two different code blocks in Org mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, python

I have an `org-mode` file containing a table of data and two Python code blocks to extract different summaries from it.

I would like to share some common constants and functions between these two code blocks.  Ideally, I'd do this by factoring out the common code into a separate code block, which would be automatically included and evaluated whenever either of the other two blocks is evaluated.  In made-up syntax, it would look something like the following:

```
#+NAME: init_block
#+BEGIN_SRC python
  ... common constants and functions here ...
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: summary_1
#+BEGIN_SRC python :prepend init_block
  ... data-processing code depending on init code goes here ...
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: summary_2
#+BEGIN_SRC python :prepend init_block
  ... more processing which also depends on init code ...
#+END_SRC
```

I suppose I could use the `:session` option, but I would prefer not to, for two reason.  First, it sets up a stateful system, rather than one which runs from scratch each time I use `C-c C-c` on a code block.  Second, and relatedly, I now have to remember to manually evaluate the common initialization code each time I open the file: I can't just update the data table, go to one of the summary blocks and hit `C-c C-c` to update it.

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this most easily using org-babel's [noweb reference syntax](http://orgmode.org/manual/Noweb-reference-syntax.html) for literate programming.  Here is an example:

```
* Initialization block containing function definition
#+NAME: init_block
#+BEGIN_SRC python
  constant=19
  def some_function(x):
    return constant * x
#+END_SRC

* Call the function on an integer
#+BEGIN_SRC python :noweb yes 
  <<init_block>>
  return some_function(13)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 247

* Call the function on a string
:PROPERTIES:
:noweb:    yes
:END:

#+BEGIN_SRC python :noweb yes 
  <<init_block>>
  return some_function('abc')
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc
```

Comment: Thank you.  This looks great, much better than my hackish solution.  I will try it out in the next few days and see if I have any problems.

Answer (score 5):

After thinking a little more I found a partial solution to this problem.  It does use `:session`, but I can at least ensure that the common initialisation code is always run automatically before evaluating one of the other blocks.  The 'trick' is to use a dummy header variable that refers to the header block, causing it to be evaluated each time:

```
#+NAME: init_block
#+BEGIN_SRC python :session t
  constant=19
  def some_function(x):
    return constant * x
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC python :session t :var dummy=init_block
some_function(13)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 247
```

Now I can change definitions in `init_block` and have them automatically re-evaluated whenever another block which refers to it using `:var dummy=init_block` is evaluated.  This works well provided that the definitions in `init_block` are idempotent and stateless.

(Note that when changing Python blocks to `:session` mode you have to remove any `return` statements, which are needed in functional mode to return a value from the block).